# Resize UIImage to fit UIImageView in Swift

Tags: swift, image, resize

I am trying to change the image of a imageview programmatically after it has been downloaded.

It works fine - it downloads the image but I have 1 problem.

When I change the image of the uiimageview, it changes its dimensions and becomes huge, basically taking up the entire screen. I don't understand it, since I have set the uiimageview to only be 175 x 175 points in size. I know that the image I am downloading is much bigger, but I want the image to be scaled down so it just fills the available space in the imageView, but it seems my imageView is stretching to accommodate the entire image.

Is there any way around this issue?

So far I have:

```
cell.backgroundImage.image = item.image
```

simply setting it - I have also tried to change the frames both before and after, but nothing works:

```
cell.backgroundImage.frame = CGRect(x: 8, y: 15, width: 175, height: 175)
```

Hope you can help me out, I am really lost here.

Thanks all! Stay safe <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the `contentMode` of the `imageView`

```
cell.backgroundImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

this will `fill` and you can clip the extra parts of the image. by clipping them:

```
cell.backgroundImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

<sub>You can also use `.scaleAspectFit` if you prefer</sub>